# Default-Constructor when splitting file

Tags: c++, c++11

got a quick question. Why does the first programm work, but not the one when i split it into header/source file? How can i fix this? (error is that there is no default-constructor for "Stud s [line 6 main.cpp]")

Here is my code:

The working one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Stud {
private:
    string pren, surn;
    unsigned int number;
public:
    Stud(string p = "", string s = "", unsigned int n = 0) : pren(p), surn(s), number(n)
    {
        return;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Stud& st) {
        os << st.number << ", " << st.pren << " " << st.surn;
    return os;
}

};

int main() {
    Stud s;
    Stud test("x", "y", 123);
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

Now the splitted one:

stud.hpp:

```
#ifndef STUD_HPP
#define STUD_HPP
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Stud {
private:
    std::string pren, surn;
    unsigned int number;
public:
    Stud(std::string, std::string, unsigned int);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Stud&);
};
#endif
```

stud.cpp:

```
#include "stud.hpp"

Stud::Stud(std::string p = "", std::string s = "", unsigned int n = 0) : pren(p), surn(s), number(n)
{
    return;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Stud& st) {
    os << st.number << ", " << st.pren << " " << st.surn;
    return os;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stud.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Stud s;
    Stud test("x", "y", 123);
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

Comment: The default arguments (`= ""`) should be in the *declaration*, i.e. the header file. (And they should *not* be in the implementation.) Your compiler should have warned you about this. If it didn't then you will benefit from enabling more warnings (not just for this particular issue).

Comment: Move default arguments from the definition to the declaration. Otherwise, the compiler that only sees `stud.hpp` doesn't know that the constructor can be called with fewer than 3 arguments.

Comment: The `return;` is superfluous.